# Complex pattern matching on templace using Scala Play

Tags: templates, scala, view, playframework-2.0, matching

I am trying to iterate over a complex value inside a template using Scala Play framework 2.

My variable is the following: `tests: List[(String,Option[List[String]])]`

I iterate on it like this:

```
@if(!tests.isEmpty) {
<h3>Tests results</h3>
@tests.map(t => {

<h4>@t._1</h4>

@t._2 match {
case None => {
<p>
  <span>
    [WARNING] Test failed
  </span>
</p>
}
case Some(res) {
@res.map(r => {
<p>
  <span>
    @r
  </span>
</p>
})}
}

})}
```

but I got the following error: `expected start of definition` on `@t._2 match {`.

I guessed that the problem comes from the fact that I use a tuple inside a map. But why? Is there any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the way you're using curly braces and parenthesis with `map`. Everything inside the parenthesis will be treated as scala code. You won't be able to use html and to use the `@` as you're expecting it to work. Inside the curly braces you can use the `@` that way you want.

For instance, this won't compile and will raise the `expected start of definition`:

```
@(tests: List[(String,Option[List[String]])])

<h3>Tests results</h3>

@tests.map( t => {  
  <h4>@t._1</h4>
  @t._2
})
```

On the other hand, this will compile and work the way it's supposed to:

```
@(tests: List[(String,Option[List[String]])])

<h3>Tests results</h3>

@tests.map{ t =>   
  <h4>@t._1</h4>
  @t._2
}
```

I had had problems with the way the template parses the scala code. I'm not entirely sure if they parse it the way the scala compiler parses a scala code. I've read before that there're some limitations. And I'll show you one in a bit. Your solution compiles and works just fine if you switch the curly braces. And you'll end up with something like that:

```
@(tests: List[(String,Option[List[String]])])

<h3>Tests results</h3>

@tests.map{  t =>  
<h4>@t._1</h4>

@defining(t._2) { optLst => 
  @optLst match {
    case None => {
        <p>
          <span>
            [WARNING] Test failed
          </span>
        </p>
    }
    case Some(res) => {
        @res.map{r => 
        <p>
          <span>
            @r
          </span>
        </p>
        }
    }
  }
}

}
```

This is not the most idiomatic way to do it. I would probably use a map instead of pattern matching there. But use what fits you. The point here is that `@defining` there. Have you noticed it? If you try to match with t._2 directly you'll get a `')' expected but 'case' found.` exception. What is odd to me. And I've found that before and I've googled it a lot to find out that this is a problem in the current engine and that you have to define the value and then match it the way you want to.

Cheers!